# When returning an iterator, is it better to return iterator type or actual object

Tags: c++, iterator

In my code below, a value is looked up in a hash table and I am puzzling over what to do if the key is not found in the map.

Is it better to return the iterator so the caller can check that?

Is it better to raise an exception?

Or do something else?

Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

struct binary_message
{
    binary_message(std::initializer_list<unsigned char> data) : bytes_(data) {}
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes_;
};


// warning C4715: 'lookup_msg' : not all control paths return a value
static const binary_message& lookup_msg(const std::string& key) {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, binary_message> table =
    {
        { "msg1", { 0x60, 0x23, 0x80, 0x02, 0x07, 0x80, 0xa1, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x2b, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x81, 0x5a, 0xbe,
                    0x14, 0x28, 0x12, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2b, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x82, 0x1d, 0x81, 0x48, 0xa0, 0x07, 0xa0, 0x05,
                    0x03, 0x03, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00 } },
        { "msg2", { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 } },
        { "msg3", { 0x1, 0x2 } },
    };

    // what if key not found?
    std::unordered_map<std::string, binary_message>::const_iterator it = table.find(key);
    if (it != table.end())
        return it->second;
    //else
    //  ???  throw an exception?  Something else?  Or should I be returning a std::unordered_map<std::string, binary_message>::const_iterator?
}

int main()
{
    const binary_message& msg7 = lookup_msg("msg1");

    // do whatever with bytes

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just return a pointer (nullptr if the lookup failed).

Comment: I'd return maybe an iterator for it's a common approach for most of the algorithms even in the standard library, but I suggest you to return whatever you feel confident with and looks fine for the implementation of your library/program.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use-case for [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html):

```
static boost::optional<const binary_message&> lookup_msg(const std::string& key) {
    ...
    if (it != table.end()) {
        return it->second; // we have a value
    }
    else {
        return boost::none; // we do not have a value
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the return type itself knows whether or not it has a value, with no ambiguity.

Note that returning an iterator here isn't really an option, as `table` is a static local to the function - so the caller wouldn't have anything to compare it to.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design choice. You have to decide whether under normal conditions with no errors, it is acceptable for an entry not to be found.

For example, if your data structure represents houses on a street, but not all spaces on the street contain a house, not finding a house is not an error and should return an iterator to compare with end (or a pointer which can be null, or a flag, or some such..)

On the other hand, if every accessible space on the street must contain a house, then throwing an exception is a suitable choice if a house is not found.

Even if you go for the first approach, searching for a house beyond the maximum address of the street could still throw an exception if you prefer.

If you are not sure which approach to use, consider the typical use case. If you throw an exception, your user will not need to manually check that every request found an item, simplifying their work if not finding an item is something stops them in their tracks (error, abort, etc).

On the other hand, if they expect not to find an item regularly, then making them catch exceptions every time is annoying and also inefficient.

There's also nothing to stop you from providing two functions, which handle not finding an item differently, but don't overthink things.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Returning an iterator to the end element is useful if you can compare to the end element returned by the member function of the container. Throwing an exception is useful because accessing that data will likely also throw an exception if you return an iterator pointing to bad memory. Also you can do what some other map-like types do and return a pair of the result (true/false) and the iterator result.

Iterator

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, binary_message>::const_iterator it = table.find(key);
if (it != table.end())
    return it->second;
else
    return table.end();

const binary_message& msg7 = lookup_msg("msg1");
if(msg7 == table.end())
 // whatever
```

Exception

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, binary_message>::const_iterator it = table.find(key);
if (it != table.end())
    return it->second;
else
    throw some_exception("Couldn't find element.");
```

Pair

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, binary_message>::const_iterator it = table.find(key);
if (it != table.end())
    return std::pair<bool, iterator_type>(true, it->second);
else
    return std::pair<bool, iterator_type>(false, table.end());

const binary_message& msg7 = lookup_msg("msg1");
if(msg7.first)
  // Do stuff
else
  // Error out
```